# C# WP8 Get selected content from listPicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I can't find a way to get and show the content of the current selected item, here is the XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="lp" Header="Network" SelectionChanged="selectionChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="aaa" />
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="bbb" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and the rest of the code:

```
private void selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.RemovedItems != null && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                if (this.lp.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    var selectedItem = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
                    int selindex = lp.SelectedIndex; //just for testing
                    MessageBox.Show(selindex.ToString()); //just for testing
                    string text = (lp.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It gives me this exception at "string text..." line:

> *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*

Comment: Which line do you get the exception on? You may need to take away your catch block to see this.

Comment: It gives me the exception at the "string text..." line. The rest is working fine, it gives me the current index.

Comment: I think this link might answer your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325243/trying-to-get-a-windows-phone-8-listpicker-to-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listpicker error SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719682/listpicker-error-selecteditem-must-always-be-set-to-a-valid-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try using code below

```
try
{
   if (e.RemovedItems != null && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
   {
        if (this.mode.SelectedItem != null)
        {
             var selectedItem = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
             int selindex = mode.SelectedIndex; //just for testing
             MessageBox.Show(selindex.ToString()); //just for testing
             string text = (selectedItem as ListPickerItem).Content.ToString();
        }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: It is always better to describe what is the solution of the OP's problem than just posting piece of raw code.